# How do I check if a value nothing in it?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to check the value length for `<ss:Id>4566</ss:Id>` if it is greater than zero. For now I don't know if this is a string or integer.
I also want to check if `<ss:Chapter>169</ss:Chapter>` the value length is greater than zero. For now I don't know if this is a string or integer.

Xml:

```
<ss:GetStatutesRequest>
    <ss:Statute>
        <ss:StatueId>
            <ns:Id>67890</ss:Id>
        </ss:StatueId>
            <ss:Chapter>169</ss:Chapter>
    </ss:Statute>
</ss:GetStatutesRequest>
```

VB code:

```vb
'Check to see if the length for Id in the ss:StatuteId node is greater than zero  
If Not objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:StatueId/ss:Id", objXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing Then

 aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("StatuteId found.", 1)

 ElseIf Not objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:Chapter", objXMLNameSpaceManager) Is Nothing Then
 aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Chapter found.", 1)
 Else
                aobjBroker.Reply(aobjBroker.CreateSoapFault(Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.Soap.udtSoapCodes.Sender, "StatuteId or Chapter is required.", Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.Soap.udtSoapRoles.RoleUltimateReceiver, aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc, "soap:InvalidMessage", "soap:Body", Msc.Integration.Utility.Library.v4.Soap.GetReplyEndpointReference(aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc), aobjXMLInputSoapEnvelopeDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("soap:Header/wsa:MessageID", objXMLNameSpaceManager).InnerText, aobjConsumer))
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Use [Integer.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: No idea how to do that.

Comment: So where in my code do I add this `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Node.Value)` And how do I check for the Chapter if there is a value? I am check for two things if they have a value 1. `<ns:StatueId>` is its `<ns:Id></ns:Id>` has a value and 2. If `ns:Chapter>169</ns:Chapter>` has a value.

Comment: You can lead a horse to water, or so I'm told ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `SelectSingleNode` and comparing the result to `Nothing`. But the node does exist, so it will not be `Nothing`. If the node exists, you should take the node that `SelectSingleNode` returns and do this check:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(Node.Value)
```

Of course, this will only look at the value of the node as string (because `Value` is always a string). So it will check if there is at least one character in the node. It doesn't check if it's valid (or even if it's a number). But from your question I understood that this is what you need.

Edit:
I'm not really a VB.NET person (more C#), but I would probably do it like this. Your code has a minor problem with the logic - if the first field ("StatueId/Id") is found, it will not check the second field.

```
    Dim IdNode = objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:StatueId/ss:Id", objXMLNameSpaceManager)
    Dim ChapterNode = objXmlGetStatuteRequestNode.SelectSingleNode("ss:Statute/ss:StatueId/ss:Id", objXMLNameSpaceManager)

    Dim BothFound = True

    If Not (IdNode Is Nothing Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(IdNode.Value)) Then
        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("StatuteId found.", 1)
    Else
        BothFound = False
    End If

    If Not (ChapterNode Is Nothing Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(ChapterNode.Value)) Then
        aobjBroker.PostMessageWarehouseInformationalMessage("Chapter found.", 1)
    Else
        BothFound = False
    End If

    If BothFound Then
        'continue processing
    Else
        'error
    End If
```

Btw is it supposed to be "statute" or "statue"?

Comment: Vesan you are right. So where in my code do I add this `String.IsNullOrEmpty(Node.Value)`

Comment: @Angela: Added a code snippet. I haven't tested it, but hopefully something very similar to this should work.